# LeetCode challenge|| Python || 645. Set Mismatch | I encountered a confusing error

Tags: python, set, mismatch

So, I was trying to solve this problem in leetcode :(this is a direct link to the problem : [Set Mismatch - LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/set-mismatch/) ).

You have a set of integers s, which originally contains all the numbers from 1 to n. Unfortunately, due to some error, one of the numbers in s got duplicated to another number in the set, which results in repetition of one number and loss of another number.

You are given an integer array nums representing the data status of this set after the error.

Find the number that occurs twice and the number that is missing and return them in the form of an array.

Example 1:

```
Input: nums = [1,2,2,4]
Output: [2,3]
```

Example 2:

```
Input: nums = [1,1]
Output: [1,2]
```

Constraints:

```
2 <= nums.length <= 10e4
1 <= nums[i] <= 10e4
```

You 'll find the code I wrote below.
So, the problem I encountered is about exceding Time for large lists. Actually,mysolution work fine (in 33/49 cases) , how can I optimize my code or get better results.

```
class Solution(object):
  def findErrorNums(self, nums):

    nums.sort()
    rep_miss = [] 
    for i  in range(len(nums)) :
        for j in range(i+1, len(nums)) :
            
            if   nums[i] == nums[j] :
                rep_miss.append(nums[i])

    for i  in range(1, len(nums)+1) :
        if i not in nums : #and abs(rep_miss[0]-i ==1) :
            rep_miss.append(i)

    return rep_miss
```

Have a nice day !

Comment: The formatting of your question is confusing. You might want to revise it by using the [edit] button.

Comment: The actual limit is 1e4, not 10e4. And better link to the problem so we don't need to search it.

Comment: Hello guys ! I' m really sorry for my terrible formating, I'm still beginner with you here, so I have not get used to post here yet. Other than that Thanks to Tom Karzes for correcting my post. (Ps @kelly I have added the link of the problem above.)

Answer (score 0):

In Python it is always worth looking for ways which do not involve huge loops and indices. For example using Counter, dictionary and sets.

```
from collections import Counter

mylist = sorted([1, 2, 2, 4])
myset = {x for x in range(1, mylist[-1] + 1)}

counts = Counter(mylist)  # a dictionary of counts in mylist
dup = [x for (x, y) in counts.items() if y == 2]
miss = list(myset - set(mylist))

print(dup + miss)
```

which outputs [2, 3]

Comment: Hello dear @user19077881 ! Thanks for your clarifications, I really appreciate it, even though It seems difficult to me to understand as a Beginner in python, I 'll do my best !  :) .

Comment: My code was intended to show that for speed in Python with large data sets, you need to move on from multiple nested loops and use things like List comprehension, library functions such as Counter and Sets with their useful features. I see someone down-voted my suggestion as not being useful; but I hope it of some use as you explore more of Python.

Comment: Did you test this at LeetCode? I'd be surprised if it got accepted, given that it fails for example `[1,1]` and `[2,2]`.

Comment: Good point. A simply edit as now done to start the sequence at 1 gives correct results for [2,2] etc.  I somehow assumed it would be useful to start the sequence at an arbitrary value but as you indicate that was not in this precise question.

Comment: Still fails the other example I gave.

Comment: [1, 1] gives [1] as the duplicated item as there are no missing values. What was expected?

Comment: The value 2 is missing. Come on, that's even explicitly shown as one of LeetCode's examples.